# Xcode uiwebView local file doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I really don't know anything about Xcode.

I have this code in `ViewController.m` to have a local file in a UIWebView:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
}
```

(I saw this in a tutorial on yt : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1gmH5nuxrKk )

But Xcode says:

[image]

How do I solve this?

.

Comment: "i really don't know anything about Xcode.." - you don't need to know anything about it, really. It's sufficient to read the documentation of the APIs you're using and also a basic Objective-C language tutorial.

Comment: -1 If you have to write "I really don't know anything about Xcode", then I think it is safe to say that you haven't done much research before asking the question.

Comment: @Monolo yes i did, and this video was the best and easiest i clould find (with only good reactions), but i have this problem...

Comment: @HAS Thanks for answering but i don't know, my app crashes always… Xcode says 'failed to get the task for process 3000'…  It gives these issues : http://bit.ly/128zEd9

Comment: I've made a little demo project for you, link is in my answer... You better make another question on these errors ;)

Comment: @HAS Thank you so much for this! (can you please give the same project with the name 'Harvix' instead of 'DemoForEds1999' please ? Like i said, i'm very good with web languages, but i don't know anything about Xcode…)

Comment: @eds1999 Thanks for accepting the answer ;) Here is your project: https://bitbucket.org/dennis_weissmann/harix

Comment: @HAS Eh really, thank you very much for helping me, i sound so rude now, but i said Harvix… not Harix… With a V in it..

Comment: @HAS Can you change that please ?

Comment: Of course, my fault, Im sorry, should be available in a few minutes ;)

Comment: right link is in answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

to

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]]]];
```

**Edit:** I've just made a very very basic and simple project which you can download and use.

It's on [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/dennis_weissmann/harvix/overview)